# pytest parameterize tests with a fixture

Tags: pytest, fixtures

I want to parameterize my tests with configuration files, which means I can't use the syntax:

```
@pytest.fixture(
    params=[
        None,
        '172.16.xxx.xxx',
        '172.16.xxx.xx',
        '172.16.xxx.xxx',
        '172.16.xxx.xx'
    ],
    ids=[
        'Local',
        'Windows10',
        'Centos7.6',
        'Ubuntu18.04',
        'Mojave'
    ],
    scope='module'
)
def endpoint(request) -> str:
    yield request.param
```

So I need something like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def endpoint(request) -> str:
    hosts = get_hosts_for_module(request.fspath, request.session.startdir)
    ...

    for host in hosts:
        host.setup_for_test()
        yield host.ip
        host.teardown_for_test()
```

That runs every test `len(hosts)` times, with a different `endpoint` value each time. The syntax above doesn't seem to work and is only running the tests for the first host in `hosts`.

Any idea what's the right syntax here?